Firebird + SQLAlchemy: non-latin symbols in path to db
I'm trying to open a Firebird database with cyrillic characters in the path, something like this
path_to_fdb = 'D:/базы/mydb.FDB'
db_url = f'firebird+fdb://sysdba:masterkey@localhost/{path_to_fdb}?charset=utf8'
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(db_url)
conn = engine.connect()

but always get an error like this
(fdb.fbcore.DatabaseError) ('Error while connecting to database:\n- SQLCODE: -902\n- I/O error during "CreateFile (open)" operation for file "D:/Р±Р°Р·С‹/mydb.FDB"\n- Error while trying to open file\n- Системе не удается найти указанный путь. ', -902, 335544344)

with gibberish in path like D:/Р±Р°Р·С‹/mydb.FDB
Obviosly, everything works fine with latin only. I understand that the problem is in the encoding of path_to_fdb, or rather with its reading, but no matter how i tried to use .encode() .decode() on this with various encodings nothing really helps.
It looks like sqlalchemy-firebird or fdb doesn't understand сyrillic symbols in path to database.
Is there a different way to load db with non-latin symbols in path?
Firebird database version - 2.5, SQLAlchemy==2.0.30, sqlalchemy-firebird==2.1, fdb==2.0.2, firebird-base==1.8.0
, firebird-driver==1.10.4

The firebird-base and firebird-driver versions are not relevant, as you're using FDB (which is deprecated and replaced by firebird-driver). You need to provide a [mre], and specifically an example of the actual path it breaks on. Also verify you're actually using a Firebird 2.5 (or higher) fbclient.dll. That said, I'm not sure if FDB actually sets the right property for fbclient to support UTF-8 path names.

@MarkRotteveel I am actually using Firebird SQL Server version - 2.5.9.27139.  Database version is also 2.5. And according to documentation of sqlalchemy-firebird if I need to access a Firebird version 2.5 server, the only possible driver for this is fdb. firebird-driver can only be used for version 3 and higher.
My original question has an example of a path where it's not working. This happens in all cases when there is cyrillic in the path to db.

@MarkRotteveel Also if I'm trying to use version 3.0 server and firebird-driver I'm getting an error (firebird.driver.types.DatabaseError) unsupported on-disk structure for file D:\mydb.FDB; found 11.2, support 12.2. And if I'm trying to add in path non-latin symbols I'm getting the same error with gibberish. Seems like firebird-driver also doesn't support utf-8 path names.

That is because Firebird 3.0 cannot read database of Firebird 2.5 (ODS 11.2) and older. To be able to access a database with Firebird 3.0, you'd need to back it up under Firebird 2.5 and restore it under Firebird 3.0. I wasn't aware that firebird-driver requires Firebird 3+ (I thought it only required a Firebird 3.0 or higher client library, which can still talk to older versions, but it seems I was wrong there in the case of firebird-driver). Then again, Firebird 2.5 has been end-of-life for five years.
